# Standard deviation of timestamp with timezone - in a group by clause

Tags: postgresql, standard-deviation

Here is my code:

```
select  
round(stddev(time_),2) as stddev_time_of_logs,
imei,mob_date,hour_of_day
from hourly_data 
group by imei,mob_date,hour_of_day
```

It produces the following error:

```
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function stddev(timestamp with time zone) does not exist
```

This is how an aggregate function is usually used, so I do not know what the issue is here. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: There's only [`stddev ( numeric_type )`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-aggregate.html); `timestamp with time zone` types cannot be passed to it directly. You'd need to convert the timestamp to a numeric type first.

Comment: How can a timestamp be converted to a number? Logically it does not seem plausible.

Comment: Then what result do you expect from a "standard deviation of a timestamp"?

Comment: I want to see average dispersion in that one hour slot, for example [10:10, 10:20, 10:30, 10:40, 10:50] has more dispersion per hour than [10:10 , 10:15, 10:20]

Comment: Basically, I want to see average dispersion for every "hour_of_day", for example [10:10, 10:20, 10:30, 10:40, 10:50] has average dispersion of 15 minutes around the mean time of 10:30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert to seconds since the Epoch and back to an interval:

```
make_interval(secs => stddev(extract (epoch FROM _time)))
```